# How can I get the longest stack trace possible?

Tags: java, stack-trace

**Problem:** Exceedingly complex and intimidating code with lots of reflection. The code base isn't the largest I've seen but it is a mess due to high demands and under-financing. We have entire departments (QA, Prod Support, etc. ) that are absent due to lack of funds. We have test coverage that probably averages 60% and integration tests aren't really assembled correctly for a solid real-world trace.   We also have no design documents. The code tends to defeat new hires as a consequence.

**Objective:** Create a sequence diagram that details the primary path of execution.

**Approach:** The approach that I'm considering is to dump a stack trace of a stem-to-stern run of a minimal data set. Then use this to build the diagram. I can parse it using Linux command line text processing tools since I have cygwin at my disposal.

**Question:** How can this be achieved? In most every case I've seen so far, something truncates the stack trace. :-/

Comment: Why don't you use debugger for this purpose. Eclipse and IntelliJ have very nice tools for debugging. Using breakpoints it is easy to see the path of execution. Stack traces get truncated because the lines that are truncated are redundant. In other words they are repeating and are already listed above. You can also utilize `ExceptionUtils` from `common.apache`

Comment: Perhaps using instrumentation, and designate the starting class/method and the target class/method.  Internally, use a `Stack` to keep track of the execution path between the start and target,   [This example](https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-instrumentation/) is old but might be helpful.  Once the path is found, write the path to a file for other tooling.

Comment: Might some AOP be helpful? Like I could log each method name when it's called? IDK how I would get the name though.  Perhaps with reflection?  This would have to mean deterministic logging. I can't have them out of order... but then again I could sort by date/time and I don't think we have much, if anything for multi-threading.  It's possible that something like that is lurking in this forest, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use debugger for this purpose. Eclipse and IntelliJ have very nice tools for debugging. Using breakpoints or debug log, it is easy to see the path of execution. Stack traces get truncated because the lines that are truncated are redundant. In other words they are repeating in nature and are already listed/printed in the stack trace that you can see. For example when you are calling a method repeatedly and somewhere in that an exception is thrown, your stack trace contains only one instance of it which is the latest, other are all truncated. That is why you see something like `45... more`.

You can also utilize `ExceptionUtils` from `org.apache.commons` which is more readable.
Specifically `printRootCauseStackTrace`.
Please refer : [apache common](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html)

To get complete auditing and understanding structure and flow use `log4j2`

Comment: Naturally this is what I've tried to use in the past. It's been a while since I tried though.

Comment: Usually your code base may contain native parts and may also include scripting languages and plugins too and so `stack traces` are the best bet.